# Open Pdf file on web page in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, web-services, pdf, response-entity

```
@GetMapping(value = "/pdf",produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getTermsConditions() throws Exception {

        String filePath = "C:\\";
        String fileName = "PDF.pdf";
        File file = new File(filePath+fileName);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
//        headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" +fileName);
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(file.length())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
                .body(resource);
    }
```

Open file, but  format is incorrect.

*���� 6 0 obj << /Type /ExtGState /BM /Normal /ca 1 >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Type /ExtGState /BM /Normal /CA 1 >> endobj 10 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 156465 /Length eP}��&֓�����*

Please help me. I want to open book pdf in browser like online library

Comment: I get same error!

Comment: It works for me (though it downloads the PDF instead of displaying it in the browser). Can you better describe what happens? What do you mean by "Open file"? In what program is the below output display? What browser are you using? Can you also show the details of the HTTP request (e.g. screen shot from browser's inspector).

Answer (score 1):

Using value "attachment" for response header "Content-Disposition" will download the PDF . Instead of displaying it in new tab.

Value "inline" for response header "Content-Disposition" will open the PDF in new tab in browser.

For example:

v1

```
headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=PDF.pdf");
```

v2

```
headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline;filename=PDF.pdf");
```

You can review: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: It's not "CONTENT_DISPOSITION", it's "CONTENT-DISPOSITION". "CONTENT_DISPOSITION" does not work.

Comment: i mean this; headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline;filename=PDF.pdf");

Comment: You better provide a code example. Otherwise people will write `headers.add("CONTENT_DISPOSITION", ...);` and wonder why it doesn't work. Even better would be `headers.addContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.inline().filename(fileName).build());`

Comment: @Codo You said is true. I'm updating.